# How to plot multiple graphs in one figure in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a problem when plotting two datasets in one figure. The second dataset (B(57,4)) were derived from the first one (2000+,10)(average, std). In the end, I want to get figure like this:

[image: aimFigure]

Now I use the code following to plot the second dateset:

```
my.data<-read.table(paste(i,"myTS.dat",sep = ""),header = TRUE)
x<-my.data$time
y<-my.data$wl
sd<-my.data$wlsd
tiff(paste(i,".tiff",sep = ""),height=3815,width=4305,unit='px',compression="lzw",res=360)
gg<-qplot(x,y,xlab = "time",ylab = "Elevation")
gg_type1<-geom_line(colour = "blue",size = 0.5)
gg_type2<-geom_point(size = 3,shape=21,fill="white")
gg_bar<-geom_errorbar(aes(x = x,ymin = y-sd,ymax=y+sd),colour = "red",width=0.05) 
gg_theme<-theme_set(theme_bw())+ theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(colour=NA))

p<-gg+gg_type1+gg_type2+gg_bar+gg_theme
print(p)
dev.off()
```

And get figure like this:
[image: myFigure]

How to add the first dataset to the figure just like the grey points in first picture? I tried this but it didn't work.

```
origin<-read.table(paste("origin_",i,".txt",sep = ""),header = TRUE)
xo<-(origin$time)
yo<-(origin$height) 
p<-gg+gg_type1+gg_type2+gg_bar+gg_theme+geom_point(aes(xo,yo))
```

Any suggestions or help are greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Okay, I put the `my.data` here:

```
structure(list(time = c(2010.586, 2010.74, 2010.819, 2010.822, 
2010.901, 2011.052, 2011.132, 2011.205, 2011.285, 2011.364, 2011.444, 
2011.518, 2011.597, 2011.677, 2011.748, 2011.827, 2011.83, 2012.06, 
2012.063, 2012.142, 2012.213, 2012.292, 2012.372, 2012.525, 2012.604, 
2012.683, 2012.757, 2012.836, 2013.066, 2013.068, 2013.148, 2013.219, 
2013.299, 2013.381, 2013.452, 2013.46, 2013.532, 2013.611, 2013.69, 
2013.844, 2013.923, 2013.997, 2014.077, 2014.156, 2014.23, 2014.307, 
2014.389, 2014.46, 2014.468, 2014.54, 2014.622, 2014.701, 2014.773, 
2014.852, 2014.855, 2014.934, 2015.085), wl = c(4716.69614519141, 
4717.18695721942, 4716.95137413031, 4716.95215915847, 4716.95617293713, 
4716.73451112085, 4716.91538177926, 4717.00588936267, 4716.78311524661, 
4716.88238213472, 4716.98192878285, 4716.97499735093, 4716.96400457306, 
4717.15611670712, 4716.99386029174, 4717.05634753127, 4716.96808398258, 
4717.3385179692, 4716.69473283737, 4717.0563764012, 4716.97307380063, 
4717.54419855758, 4716.6528308359, 4716.79914374548, 4716.87207534116, 
4716.70372924768, 4716.88957602414, 4716.77689686401, 4717.089005203, 
4716.79885280683, 4717.32157811021, 4716.4542772104, 4716.57303829829, 
4716.69165719355, 4716.75878030774, 4716.51425619761, 4716.69628661921, 
4716.76718193149, 4716.83711216341, 4716.56437245363, 4716.80095589741, 
4716.92953229352, 4716.54242002516, 4719.15933244319, 4716.60029813372, 
4716.77020818021, 4716.46140477099, 4716.89015101807, 4717.00917071744, 
4716.45796269575, 4716.71523494857, 4716.42773085329, 4716.16425299646, 
4716.56107921007, 4716.89280970058, 4716.72261405892, 4716.88387012439
), wlsd = c(0.216549886343437, 0.0482189681060723, 0.0588960842643573, 
0.175719434105253, 0.0512158233301561, 0.0392292465112816, 0.0595950831354654, 
0.0607877904822251, 0.0370930552408838, 0.617268490833093, 0.0383914957042668, 
0.605527813866314, 0.0543574451035527, 0.0545768826476366, 0.0507742835767385, 
0.0583394912905697, 0.0563566145080252, 0.0912149956407483, 0.0448705108316624, 
0.069484057343461, 0.0458673635595506, 0.0758663652549518, 0.0379866112968593, 
0.706702525314332, 0.0424187676989381, 0.0371769559424733, 0.0593394645898105, 
0.0502308178338169, 0.0539188048527388, 0.0557205808317756, 0.0960199790307439, 
0.0377344405056613, 0.623137480604024, 0.0450269480801559, 0.0638249721374399, 
0.0375489717974975, 0.0376544472258395, 0.622074959650495, 0.186283259878619, 
0.0492906734226584, 0.0523743622696856, 0.0486222624919726, 0.115848182732971, 
0.115018243869508, 0.0427547194026263, 0.0702039197853462, 0.0414918973327205, 
0.0520070741917287, 0.0585758170986699, 0.0377079876736141, 0.0392247467180624, 
0.616261504979872, 0.263302559470029, 0.0486800241034257, 0.0514939409350517, 
0.0509628426691605, 0.0480276613429565)), .Names = c("time", 
"wl", "wlsd"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -57L))
```

The original data are quite long to post. Just similar to `my.data`, but contains more rows.

Comment: Instead of `geom_point(aes(xo,yo))` add `geom_point(data = origin, aes(x = time, y = height))`. I you want more help, you will probably need to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank Axeman. But it still does not work. [ ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval.] The two datasets have different length. Specifically, dataset 2 is the statistics of dataset 1.

Comment: @iscaler If you have a minimal dataset to put into your post, and it is in `my.data`, you can use the output of `dput(my.data)`.  This should create a result that can be cut and pasted to load the data in R quite easily.

Comment: @steveb Okay, I used dput(my.data) to get the data.

Comment: Why exactly does your code not work? Error message? In what way is it not your expected result?

Comment: Thanks all. Now I figure it out using the code below:    p<-gg+gg_type1+gg_type2+gg_bar+gg_theme+geom_point(data = origin,aes(x = xo,y = yo))

Comment: @iscaler You may want to add your final answer as an answer.